# Anyone have an JavaScript example of the Adfly official API?

Tags: javascript, node.js

The official Adfly API has very poor documentation.
So, they say that to make a request you have 2 auth types:

1. Basic, only 2 parameters.
2. HMAC that includes some sha256 hashes.

Good, at the moment I follow all the steps but in a moment I cant understand what's going on.

My code:

```js
function computehash(key, update){
  const hash = crypto
  .createHmac(`sha256`, key)
  .update(serialize(update))
  .digest(`base64`);
  console.log(hash)
  return hash
}
async function account(){
  let url = "https://api.adf.ly/v1/account"
  let timestamp = Math.round(new Date().getTime()/1000)
  //let toencode = "_user_id="+userId+"&_api_key="+apiKey+"&_timestamp="+timestamp
      let data = {
    "_user_id": userId,
    "_api_key": apiKey,
    "_timestamp": timestamp//,
    //"_hash": computehash(privateKey, dad)
  }
  dad._hash = computehash(privateKey, data)
  console.log(serialize(data))
  let res = await axios.post(url, serialize(dad), headers)
  console.log(res.data)
}
account();
```

Here's the API documentation and some examples:

- [Official documentation](https://%61%64%66.%6c%79/static/other/adfly_api_v1_documentation.pdf?v=20191108)
- [Official examples](https://%61%64%66.%6c%79/static/other/AdflyApiExamples.zip?v=20180819)

Comment: What is the problem when you use this code? Do you get any result? Any error?

Comment: The error is that the API says that hashes do not match, but i dont know how to make the request